# Sum of divisors of a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am trying to get some hint as to whether there exists a perfect square which has a power of a prime p to even degree 4 or higher and the sum of divisors divides the same prime p but to only one degree less than the perfect square?

Comment: Do you mean the sum of divisors *divides* $p$, or *is divisible by* $p$?

Comment: divisible by p is what I meant sorry

Comment: Ping me if/when you edit it, and we can delete this interchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. $$242144721$$ is a square divisible by $3^4$. The sum of its divisors is divisible by $3^3$ , but not by $3^4$

Comment: thanks Peter that's exactly what I was interested in

Comment: if you find anymore please share

Comment: Another example is $$(5\cdot 11\cdot 31\cdot 41)^4$$ which is divisible by $5^4$ and the sum of its divisors is divisble by $5^3$ , but not $5^4$

Comment: for the second example in the comments list, is there any chance that the sums of divisors of that number is divisible by 3